# Using caps on videoscale element in Gstreamer C API

Tags: c, gstreamer

I'm trying to grab video from a window using `ximagesrc` and scale it to a certain size before encoding in H.264 and streaming with RTP to another machine. I implemented my pipeline in the C API and it works fine unless I add a `videoscale` element with `capsfilter`.

Specifically, I have a problem understanding how to use the `videoscale` element correctly and how to link it with a `videoconvert` element programmatically. The function `gst_element_link_filtered` returns false when I try to connect the `videoconvert` and `videoscale` element using a `capsfilter` for scaling to the resolution I want.

My code looks as follows:

```
static gboolean
link_elements_with_filter (GstElement *element1, GstElement *element2)
{
  gboolean link_ok;
  GstCaps *caps;

  caps = gst_caps_from_string("video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=20/1");

  link_ok = gst_element_link_filtered (element1, element2, caps);
  gst_caps_unref (caps);

  if (!link_ok) {
      g_warning ("Failed to link element1 and element2!");
    }

  return link_ok;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

(...)

 /* Create the elements */
  source = gst_element_factory_make ("ximagesrc", "source");
  converter = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "converter");
  scaler = gst_element_factory_make ("videoscale", "scaler");
  encoder = gst_element_factory_make("nvh264enc", "encoder");
  payloader = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264pay", "payloader");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsink", "sink");

  g_object_set (source, "use-damage", FALSE, "xid", 0x5c0000c, NULL);
  g_object_set (encoder, "gop-size", 25, "rc-mode", 2, "bitrate", 2000, NULL);
  g_object_set (payloader, "config-interval", 1, NULL); 
  g_object_set (sink, "host", "172.17.25.248", "port", 5004, NULL);

  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

  if (!pipeline || !source || !converter || !encoder || !payloader || !sink) {
      g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
      return -1;
  }


   gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, converter, scaler, encoder, payloader, sink,   NULL);
   if ((gst_element_link (source, converter) && link_elements_with_filter(converter, scaler)
                                          && gst_element_link (scaler, encoder)
                                          && gst_element_link (encoder, payloader)
                                          && gst_element_link (payloader, sink)) != TRUE) {
    g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return -1;
}

(...)
```

When I run this code,  I get the following output:

```
** (gst_server:55698): WARNING **: 11:21:57.315: Failed to link element1 and element2!
Elements could not be linked.
Process finished with exit code 255
```

So I have problems connecting the `videoconvert` and `videoscale` elements. Is there something wrong with the order of the elements in the pipeline, or perhaps with my usage of caps?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The corresponding `gst-launch` pipeline (which works fine) looks like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc use-damage=FALSE xid=0x5c0000c ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 ! nvh264enc gop-size=25 rc-mode=cbr bitrate=2000 ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=172.X.X.X port=5001
```

I can then start another `gst-launch` pipeline on the client machine and see the scaled video.

**EDIT 2:**
I set `GST_DEBUG=5` and inspected the debug output. It says that the source pad of the `videoconvert` element and the sink pad of the `capsfilter` element are not compatible. It seems there is an issue with the conversion between media formats.

```
0:00:00.175919763 57549 0x5578d0241800 DEBUG               GST_CAPS gstutils.c:3065:gst_pad_query_caps:<capsfilter0:sink> query returned video/x-raw, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)20/1
0:00:00.175938538 57549 0x5578d0241800 DEBUG               GST_CAPS gstpad.c:2278:gst_pad_link_check_compatible_unlocked:<converter:src> src caps video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx, width=(int)1247, height=(int)1573, framerate=(fraction)[ 1/2147483647, 2147483647/1 ], pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1; video/x-raw, width=(int)1247, height=(int)1573, framerate=(fraction)[ 1/2147483647, 2147483647/1 ], pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string){ I420, YV12, YUY2, UYVY, AYUV, VUYA, RGBx, BGRx, xRGB, xBGR, RGBA, BGRA, ARGB, ABGR, RGB, BGR, Y41B, Y42B, YVYU, Y444, v210, v216, Y210, Y410, NV12, NV21, GRAY8, GRAY16_BE, GRAY16_LE, v308, RGB16, BGR16, RGB15, BGR15, UYVP, A420, RGB8P, YUV9, YVU9, IYU1, ARGB64, AYUV64, r210, I420_10BE, I420_10LE, I422_10BE, I422_10LE, Y444_10BE, Y444_10LE, GBR, GBR_10BE, GBR_10LE, NV16, NV24, NV12_64Z32, A420_10BE, A420_10LE, A422_10BE, A422_10LE, A444_10BE, A444_10LE, NV61, P010_10BE, P010_10LE, IYU2, VYUY, GBRA, GBRA_10BE, GBRA_10LE, BGR10A2_LE, GBR_12BE, GBR_12LE, GBRA_12BE, GBRA_12LE, I420_12BE, I420_12LE, I422_12BE, I422_12LE, Y444_12BE, Y444_12LE, GRAY10_LE32, NV12_10LE32, NV16_10LE32, NV12_10LE40 }
0:00:00.175947929 57549 0x5578d0241800 DEBUG               GST_CAPS gstpad.c:2280:gst_pad_link_check_compatible_unlocked:<capsfilter0:sink> sink caps video/x-raw, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)20/1
0:00:00.175955981 57549 0x5578d0241800 DEBUG               GST_CAPS gstpad.c:2298:gst_pad_link_check_compatible_unlocked: caps are not compatible
0:00:00.175960969 57549 0x5578d0241800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2434:gst_pad_link_prepare: caps are incompatible
0:00:00.175968231 57549 0x5578d0241800 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2529:gst_pad_link_full: link between converter:src and capsfilter0:sink failed: no common format
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of I would recommend to use `gst_parse_launch()`. You can create pipelines for you application like you would run via `gst-launch-1.0`. You can then access individual elements by iterating or searching for them if needed - most of the stuff can be described with the pipeline string though.

For your code. You have set the caps before the scaler. Which means the scaler input should have these caps. However the `ximagesrc` defines the actual size. If it isn't the exact the one you have given it will fail.

Usually you want to set it right before the encoder and let the elements to their job to find configuration to satisfy the caps. E.g:

> ximagesrc ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! xvideo/x-raw, format=I420, width=640, height=480, framerate=20/1 ! nvh264enc ..

Here `videoconvert` will know it somehow has to convert from `ximagesrc` (Usually RGB format) to I420 and `videoscale` will scale from whatever resolution `ximagesrc` provides to 640x480. `ximagesrc` will be advised to capture at 20 fps.

Comment: Thanks I will check `gst_parse_launch`. As you wrote, I put the filter between scaler and encoder, i.e. `link_elements_with_filter (scaler, encoder)`. Now I'm able to scale the output of ximagesrc to a desired resolution. Just a question for clarification: you wrote `ximagesrc` will be advised to captured at 20 fps. Is the limitation here the screen refresh rate or something else related to the capabilities of the graphics unit? In other words, what determines here the upper limit of capture frame rate of `ximagesrc`?

Comment: Good question. I guess one would have to look at the source of this element and maybe even further. But I would expect the upper limit will be the screen refresh rate. Maybe lower if the underlying compositor or something else in the graphics stack has a limitation (bandwidth copying the image data etc..)